# ScrollView in Fragment doesn't scroll completely

Tags: android, fragment, scrollview

i'm new to android and i have a problem with 2 Layouts on mi fragment: a LinearLayout on the top that has to always be there, and a Scrollview. The problem is that the ScrollView doesn't scroll completely, the button with text "final" is never shown. In a point the ScrollView can't go down, i don't know what the problem is, i'm sure is easy but i couldnt find the answer anywhere

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:id="@+id/relative2"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ajustes"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textColor="#004667"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#004667"
    android:id="@+id/rel21">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/user" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">



<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/linear"
   >
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button6"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Button" />
   <Button
        />
   <Button
        />
   <Button
        />
   <Button
        />

   <Button
        />
   <Button
        />
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/ad"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="final" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

EDIT: I was using BottomNavigationBar and the last button was covered by it, So i just added layout_marginBottom to the scrollview and it's working fine now. Thanks :D

Comment: test case remove **android:fillViewport="true"** from your **`ScrollView`** than try

Comment: your layout is correct update your java code..

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling at the bottom of view make sure you add the property in Scrollview, have look :

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:fillViewport="true">
</ScrollView>
```

and do in fragment:

```
scrollview.scrollTo(0, scrollview.getBottom());
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your upper layout is taking all the space and scrollview is not visible. To solve this problem give height not wrap_content. For example

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel21"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:background="#004667">
```